# Select Specific character from a column and paste the related value to another Column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Working on a 2016 version excel file where i need to copy only the specific characters which contains _ or - from a column and paste the related data into another column.

If any of the row contains "|" then remove everything after this symbol.

**Input Data:**

```
col1                                                  col2
Disconnected on B_NKLA_TUV_0022 As Per 
Roll DCN-BVLR-OCR-NKLT | Flapping
VAAP CLR_ NLTK_BKC_ASSO CBR Thing
VCR-DCW- NKL-NKJ-MLP | CBR-XDL-BHG
Disconnected on B_NFA_SUV_0025 As
```

**Steps**: First we need to remove all the character after "|" from col1
Then Exctract characters containing "*" OR "-", If there is any space between 2 sentance containing "*" OR "-", We need to combibne it and paste into col2

Output Data:

```
col1                                                  col2
Disconnected on B_NKLA_TUV_0022 As Per             B_NKLA_TUV_0022
Roll DCN-BVLR-OCR-NKLT | Flapping                  DCN-BVLR-OCR-NKLT
VAAP CLR_ NLTK_BKC_ASSO CBR Thing                  CLR_ NLTK_BKC_ASSO
Disconnected on 23 Dec 2022
VCR-DCW- NKL-NKJ-MLP | CBR-XDL-BHG                 VCR-DCW- NKL-NKJ-MLP
Disconnected on B_NFA_SUV_0025 As                  B_NFA_SUV_0025
```

Need Suggestion on it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: You can do it by formula.

Comment: @Harun24hr - Please Suggest

Comment: @JvdV - Any Suggestion on how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(A2,"|",,,,A2)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>",
"//s[contains(., '_') or contains(., '-')]"),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update , However i have tried but getting #NAME? as value in col 2.

Comment: What is your excel version? This solution will only work on `Office365`.

Comment: I amusing Excel 2016, Please Suggest the change to be made .

Comment: Harun24hr - For Excel 2016 version, Please Suggest the change that needs to be made in the above line of script.

Answer (score 2):

**Excel 2016 - Formula**:

One could try [`FILTERXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) and use a simple predicate in the xpath expression to filter the correct substring<sup>‡</sup>:

[image]

Formula in B2:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1&"|")),"- ","-|"),"_ ","_|")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'-_','')!=.]"),"|"," "),"")
```

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>You can be much more restrictive if need be with xpath. This is done through *anding* more predicates. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75214057/9758194).</sub>

---

**PowerQuery**:

Alternatively, you could load your table into PQ. Follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72179006/9758194) to add a custom function based on a regular expression and invoke this using the following regular expression:

```
^[^|]*?(\\b[A-Z0-9]+(?:[-_] ?[A-Z0-9]+)+)\\b.*$|.
```

Replace this with a backreference to the 1st capture group `$1`. Now you can, as per given link, simply replace error values with a NULL if so desired.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "fnRegexExtr", each fnRegexExtr([Col1], "^[^|]*?(\\b[A-Z0-9]+(?:[-_] ?[A-Z0-9]+)+)\\b.*$|.", "$1")),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Invoked Custom Function", {{"fnRegexExtr", null}})
in
    #"Replaced Errors"
```

---

**VBA**:

Another alternative is creating your own custom User Defined Function (UDF) through VBA, and invoke this like a formula on your sheet. For example:

```
Public Function RegexReplace(s As String, pat As String, rep As String, Optional cse As Boolean = False) As String

Static RE As Object: If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = pat
RE.IgnoreCase = cse
RegexReplace = RE.Replace(s, rep)

End Function
```

Now invoke this through using a slightly different pattern:

```
=RegexReplace(A2,"^[^|]*?(\b[A-Z0-9]+(?:[-_] ?[A-Z0-9]+)+)\b.*$|.+","$1")
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Do we have any option in Excel 2016 formula where we can keep withspaces between substrings